# Differentiability and open space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $B (0, r)$ be the open ball in R, $f: B (0, r) \to\mathbb{ R}$ a differentiable function such that $f (0) = 0.$
We suppose that it exists $k> 0$ such that $\|f'(x)\| \leq k | f (x) |$ for all $x \in B (0, r)$

First, let $s_1 \in ( 0, \min \{r, 1 / k\} )$

Let $s_2 \in ( s_1, \min \{r, 2s_1\} )$. We consider $M_2 = \max \{| f (x) | : x \in B (0, s_2)\}$. I must show that $M_2 = 0.$

I kinda figure out that $B(0,s_1) ⊂ B(0,s_2) ⊂ B(0,r)$, but then I truly don't know what to do

Comment: Do you know about/have you tried using Gronwall's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions ? I would try defining $u(s) = \max_{|x|<s} |f(x)|$ and see where that gets you.

Comment: Is $B(0,r)=(-r, r)$? Because you are writing $R$ there.